# display confirmed products for purchase in purchase order openerp

Tags: odoo

I have added new statuses(PENDING,CONFIRMED) for products. I need to display only CONFIRMED products for purchase in the purchase order. I have tried, however, not getting clear idea on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inherit the view and use domain [('status','=','confirmed')]

```
<field name="product_id" on_change="onchange_product_id(parent.pricelist_id,product_id,0,False,parent.partner_id, parent.date_order,parent.fiscal_position,date_planned,name,price_unit,context)" domain="[('state','=','confirmed')]" />
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It got worked. Now I was able to see only the CONFIRMED products in the Picking list of Purchase Orders.

Comment: Can Inheriting the view be done by Web Client through customization? Please let me know the procedure. Now it got worked for all the menus under Purchases. I want this view to work for a particular menu item. Please advise. Thanks in advance.

Comment: that's because all of them using same view, if you want a unique view for your menu then you should create the form completely instead of inheriting it and use that view for your menu

Comment: Thank you. I have created a unique view, but I am struggling to assign that view for that particular menu. Please give me some tips.

Comment: refer this links https://doc.openerp.com/6.0/developer/2_6_views_events/views/specify_view_to_use another one http://blog.instant-erp.com/2012/10/how-to-call-specific-form-tree-view.html

Comment: Thank you. Can you please help me on how to add the product status to the purchase order line? (in Product, Status, Description, Date Planned, Company etc)

Comment: just add the field in view

Comment: Thank you. I have added the field in the view. However, it's not retrieving the status of the product which I have selected. Please advise, if possible.

Comment: Detailed Explanation: I have added statuses for Product (such as PENDING, CONFIRMED, CANCELLED) as a base field . I need the status of the product(which I selected) to be displayed in the purchase order line along with other product attributes.